# GROUP BY returning duplicate values

Tags: sql

I need to have a record of all the ticket numbers that has been created by my colleagues with the dates they were created.
Upon doing so, I used GROUP BY not to have duplicate ticket number, but I am still getting 3 - 5 duplicate values.

Code:

```
SELECT        A.TICKET_NUMBER, A.CREATED_BY B.DATE_CREATED, 
FROM          Records AS A INNER JOIN
              (SELECT MAX(SYS_CREATED_ON) AS DATE_CREATED, TICKET_NUMBER
               FROM TIME_STAMP
               GROUP BY TICKET_NUMBER) AS B ON A.TICKET_NUMBER = b.TICKET_NUMBER 
ORDER BY DATE_CREATED DESC
```

Here is the example table:

```
TICKET_NUMBER    CREATED_BY    DATE_CREATED
TI123123         JOHN          2018-07-10 12:07:56
TI123123         JOHN          2018-07-10 12:07:56
TI123123         JOHN          2018-07-10 12:07:56
TI123123         JOHN          2018-07-10 12:07:56
TI123124         PETER         2018-07-10 12:07:54
TI123124         PETER         2018-07-10 12:07:54
TI123124         PETER         2018-07-10 12:07:54
TI123124         PETER         2018-07-10 12:07:54
```

Comment: try group by basic query too

Comment: Looks like your Records table has multiple record for same Ticket_Number. can you provide sample data from Records table for the ticket_number you have displayed in your result set

Comment: tag your rdbms.

Comment: @AB_87 now that I've double check it, you're right there are duplicate cord for the same ticket_number.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your table structure but if your example table is correct then you can try the following:

```
SELECT
  A.TICKET_NUMBER, 
  Max(A.CREATED_BY),
  Max(A.DATE_CREATED)
From 
  Yourtable A
Group by
  A.TICKET_NUMBER
```